# Como a propriedade "order" do CSS funciona?

Tags: css

Eu estou um pouco confuso sobre o comportamento da propriedade [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order), pelo que eu entendi ela usada para alterar ordem dos elementos (flex ou grid) no documento. E seu uso deve ser atribuído aos elementos individuais (não ao elemento pai ou contêiner), isso significa, que se eu quiser alterar a ordem de um elemento eu tenho que alterar a ordem de todos os elementos?

Exemplo:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

body div {
  margin: 20px;
}

#elem1 {
  order: 2;
}

#elem2 {
  order: 1;
}

#elem3 {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem1">Elemento 1</div>
<div id="elem2">Elemento 2</div>
<div id="elem3">Elemento 3</div>
```

No snippet acima, eu quis mudar a ordem do `#elem2` no lugar do `#elem1` e vice-versa, então eu precisei especificar a ordem de cada elemento com a propriedade `order`, ou seja, se eu tiver vários elementos filhos terei que colocar a posição de cada elemento com a propriedade `order`?

Outra dúvida minha seria neste caso:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

body div {
  margin: 20px;
}

#elem2 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem1">Elemento 1</div>
<div id="elem2">Elemento 2</div>
<div id="elem3">Elemento 3</div>
```

Por que, no snippet acima ao especificar o valor `1`, o `#elem2` é posicionado no lugar do `#elem3`? E também se fosse especificado o valor `-1`, porque o `#elem2` é movido para a primeira posição no lugar do `#elem1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, ele é usado para alterar a ordem dos elementos em contêineres flex ou grid, *mas a ordem não é exatamente individual*, os itens em um contêiner são classificados por ordem crescente de valor e em seguida, por ordem do código-fonte.

> **Note:** o uso de `order` irá afetar a ordem visual dos elementos e não a sua ordem lógica ou de tabulação.

Elementos sem a propriedade `order:` definida serão assumidos como `0` pelo *user-agent* e **você não definiu `order` nos outros elementos**, por isso eles ficarão na posição `0`, elementos com valor negativo ficarão a esquerda de elementos com `order: 0` e de elementos sem a propriedade definida, os elementos com valor positivo ficarão a direita.

Veja no exemplo que o elemento sem `order` ficará ao lado `order: 0` e no meio dos elementos negativos e positivos:

```css
body { display: flex }
body div { margin: 2px; padding: 4px; background: #ccc }
```

```html
<div style="order: 0; background: #f00">order: 0</div>
<div style="order: 2">order: 2</div>
<div style="order: 1">order: 1</div>
<div style="order: 3">order: 3</div>
<div style="order: -2">order: -2</div>
<div style="order: -1">order: -1</div>
<div style="order: -3">order: -3</div>
<div style="background: #fc0">NÃO DEFINIDO</div>
```

Note pelo *DevTools* do navegador (no meu caso Firefox) como o estilo do user-agent define o valor do elemento sem `order:` aplica o estilo com `order: 0`:

[image: DevTools do Firefox com estilo do user-agent visivel]